# Android - open external app by user clicking url on any place in app

Tags: android, kotlin, deep-linking

Got little bit confused here, because usually we would want to open OUR app from any external app, but in my case, I need to do the opposite - open external app (if it is installed) by user clicking on url inside my app (it can be any view).

Now.. First thing is first - I'm feeling that this should be classified as deeplink approach, even though direction is opposite (correct me if I'm wrong here). Also, I want to have a solution that gets triggered anywhere in the app (for instance, if dynamic content comes from server-side and it includes text + url). So setting a simple click listener on a button/link does not cut it in this case.

What I want to achieve: whenever user clicks tiktok url anywhere in the app, tiktok app should be opened if it is installed.

So, I started by implementing deep-link:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.myapp.MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https"
                android:host="www.tiktok.com" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I'd have hoped that this would trigger `onNewIntent(intent: Intent?)` inside of `MainActivity`. Which is not what I'm getting. Am I looking on this problem incorrectly? If not, which part am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Starting with Android 12, Google only allows "verified links" to be opened in external apps. Verified links allow app developers to ensure that only their app can handle links from their domain. If a link is non-verified, Android 12 will open it in the default browser, instead of showing you the app selection dialogue. But thankfully there’s an app called Better Open With that lets you get around Android 12's new link handling behavior.
[read more](https://www.xda-developers.com/android-12-will-always-open-non-verified-links-in-the-default-browser/)
also for lower android version you can do this and your second intent filter is redunant.

```
private void openLink(String url){
    Uri parsedUri = Uri.parse(url);
    Intent browseIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(parsedUri);
    browseIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    Context context;
    if (mActivity != null && mActivity.get() != null) {
        context = mActivity.get().getBaseContext();
    } else {
        context = getContext();
    }
    context.startActivity(browseIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To give you a better understanding to Hosein's answer, the only way to open another app is by using `Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)`. It is up to the developers of Tiktok (in your case) that they have deeplinks relevant to your url. Even if they have implemented them, the user could have set a browser for all links. Hence not all usecases will make Tiktok launch due to these situations out of your control.

Comment: Understood. If I'd like to open TikTok app on button click, how would I do that? Using Hoseins example and that's it or is they other way around.

Comment: No straight forward way, the closest implementation to opening Tiktok itsself is by using package manager: `val 
 intent = getLaunchIntentSenderForPackage("com.zhiliaoapp.musically")`. Then if they have an api doc for their android app, like example `URL as Intent` you can then call `intent?.putExtra("URL", "link_to_profile_or_vid")`. If the app is not installed, intent is null. Then lastly launch the intent on button click `startActivity(intent)`